# Swift: Cannot assign value of type 'ProfileViewController' to type 'CNContactPickerDelegate'?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to give the user the ability to choose contacts from his contact list but I get this error. Here is my code:

```
//  ProfileViewController.swift
//  Tracker
//  Created by user on 12/10/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Alex Cipcigan. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import ContactsUI

class ProfileViewController : UIViewController, CNContactPickerViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

var spinner : UIActivityIndicatorView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
    spinner?.color = UIColor.blueColor()
    spinner?.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(spinner!)

    spinner?.startAnimating()

    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.width / 2.0
    image.clipsToBounds = true

    self.fetchDetails { (name, image) -> Void in
        self.image.image = image
        self.name.text = name
        self.spinner?.stopAnimating()
        self.spinner?.hidden = true
    }
    print("s")
}


func fetchUserId( closure : (FBID: String, name : String) -> Void) {
    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                if let dict = result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    let fbid = dict["id"] as! String
                    let name = dict["name"] as! String
                    closure(FBID: fbid, name: name)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func fetchDetails(closure : (name : String, image: UIImage) -> Void) {
    self.fetchUserId { (FBID, name) -> Void in
        let pictureURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(FBID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: pictureURL)!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            closure(name: name, image: image!)
        })
    }
}

func pickContacts() {
    let controller = CNContactPickerViewController() //<- here I get the error: "Cannot assign value of type 'ProfileViewController' to type 'CNContactPickerDelegate'?"

    controller.delegate = self

    navigationController?.presentViewController(controller,
    animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

I have tried several things but they didn't work. What have I done wrong? 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the error occurs on the line after the one you marked!?

Comment: It occurs on the line I have marked.

Comment: 99.9% sure you are wrong since the let statement cannot cause such an error